# Git: Aren't changes supposed to stay within their branch?

Tags: git

I am relatively new to using Git. This is what I've done so far:

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git branch mywork
$ git checkout mywork
$ git branch
* mywork
  master

...modify some files...

$ git status
# On branch mywork
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file1.html
#   modified:   file2.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now if I switch to my other branch, I expect my changes to stay within this branch. However, it looks like the changes come with me:

```
$ git checkout master
M   file1.html
M   file2.html
Switched to branch 'master'

$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file1.html
#   modified:   file2.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I misunderstanding my use of Git?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why git keeps showing my changes when I switch branches (modified,added, deleted files) no matter if I run git add or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531362/why-git-keeps-showing-my-changes-when-i-switch-branches-modified-added-deleted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before switching back to your master branch, you need to add and commit your changes to the branch.

Use:

```
git checkout mywork
# Modify files

git add . # Adds all edited files to the repository
git commit -m "Message about the changes"

git checkout master
```

You can find lots of information about Git at [The Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Your working directory and your repository are separate from each other, in the sense that code in your working directory is not associated with a branch until it is committed.

To further muddy the waters, git has introduced a new concept called the index, which is a staging ground *between your working directory and repository*. When you run `git add` on a file, what you're *really* doing is adding it to the index. Likewise, when you run `git commit`, you finally add the contents of the index to the repository.

`git status` distinguishes between the index and the working directory as follows.

- `Changes to be committed:` indicates changes in the index
- `Changed but not updated:` indicates changes in the working directory to files that have already been added to the repository (and not subsequently ignored)
- `Untracked files:` indicates changes in the working directory to files that have *not* already been added to the repository

If you have a few changes that you want to save for the moment but that don't warrant their own branch, use [`git stash`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html). This is git's mechanism for creating an extremely lightweight, single-commit branch. From the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) (emphasis is mine):

> Use `git stash` when you want to record
>   the current state of *the working
>   directory and the index*, but want to
>   go back to a clean working directory.
>   The command saves your local
>   modifications away and reverts the
>   working directory to match the `HEAD`
>   commit.

Answer (score 2):

In somewhat plainer english than other (correct) answers: `git checkout` doesn't stomp files it doesn't know about. Since you haven't done `git add` on file1.html and file2.html, git doesn't know about them, and so doesn't remove them when you change branches.

If you were to `add` and `commit` them on branch mywork, they would go away when you check out master, and come back when you check out mywork.

Answer (score 1):

that is because you haven't committed them in the mywork branch. once you commit them and checkout the master branch you will not find that changes

you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) SO post very helpful

Comment: you can stash them http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html