# Visual Studio - adding a file in one branch adds the file to all branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

I've encountered some unexpected behavior in `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017` in a `.NET Web API` project. When I'm in a branch (not `master`), and I add some new files like a controller and a model, maybe exclude a file or two from project, etc. If I switch back to `master`, or to any other branch, these same files are added and/or excluded in this branch as well.

I thought the purpose of branches was to keep changes like this isolated? Perhaps changes in the file tree have always populated across branches and I just never noticed until now?

Is this behavior in Visual Studio expected?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, but if you're not _committing_ those files this is expected behaviour in Git. Uncommitted changes don't belong to _any_ branch.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6286539/354577 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5531362/354577, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modified files in a git branch are spilling over into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch)

Comment: You are correct, Chris - not committing the changes to that branch was my problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this same behavior in Visual Studio Code when adding files to the filesystem, but not when removing them. It may be different for Visual Studio Enterprise but I think this is intended. If you add files to the filesystem they don't want to delete them when you switch between branches. I think the deleted files can be brought back in by pulling from the branch. However the added files will stay until you `.gitignore` them, commit/push them, or remove them.

Comment: Ah, I see - as you and Chris pointed out - I needed to commit the changes to that branch. Thanks!