# After a git checkout I see a folder from another branch

Tags: git, checkout

I'm working on a little repo.  I have branches master, m1, m2, m3, m4 and m5. I recently worked on m4, created a directory and committed my changes.  Now I checkout m5, but that directory I just created on m4 is still there.  Trying to understand why that might be and if/what I should do about it.

e.g.

```
PS C:\Repos\mystuff> git co m5
Switched to branch 'm5'
PS C:\Repos\mystuff> git ls-tree -r --name-only m5
.gitattributes
.gitignore
LICENSE
README.md
PS C:\Repos\mystuff> git st
On branch m5
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Repos\mystuff> ls


    Directory: C:\Repos\mystuff>


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019-09-14  11:02 AM                04   <== old folder from m4
-a----       2019-07-23   7:25 PM             66 .gitattributes
-a----       2019-09-03   7:58 PM           5980 .gitignore
-a----       2019-07-23   7:25 PM           1065 LICENSE
-a----       2019-07-23   7:25 PM             32 README.md
```

Why is that old folder still showing in ls, even though it is not in the files for the branch and doesn't show as untracked?

Can/should I (safely) deleted it without messing up m4?

Comment: Are there any files in `04`? Git does not track folders, only files. Checking out `m5` should remove the files in `m4` that are not in `m5`, but it won't delete the folder unless it's empty afterwards, e.g., if it contains any untracked files, Git would not remove those.

Comment: Is it possible that your `.gitignore` has something to do with this ?

Comment: @joanis Aha, the folder is empty. so that explains it!  Thanks.  If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not track folders, only files.

Checking out `m5` should remove the files in `m4` that are not in `m5`, but it won't delete the folder unless it's empty afterwards.

For example, if it contains any untracked files, Git would not remove those files or the folder.