# Commit on master branch gets all the folders created in the testing branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I was working on a new feature, for the new feature create a branch called example. Created a lot of new folders and files in this branch.
There was a task with high priority to perform, so I went back to the master branch using **`git checkout master`**.

Now I am in the `master` branch, made the changes whatever I want to and wanted to push this to my master.

I performed **`git add -A`** and **`git commit -m 'Priority 2016'`**

This got all the created folders and files in the testing branch.
What have I done wrong?
Any Help?

Comment: `git add -A` should only have added files or folders which are either new or represent things which you have changed.  Which files/folders did you want to commit?

Comment: when you git checkout all modif are move in the branch you choice unless you commit in example branch before git checkout. you can git stash too.

Comment: I just wanted to commit only the changes I made in master not the testing branch

Comment: So you mean to say when I am in the branch every time I flipback to master i need to commit the changes and then flip back to master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2016: `git checkout master` would not remove files which were added (but not committed) in another branch: see "[Why git keeps showing my changes when I switch branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531400/6309)"

A `git reset --hard` and `git clean -f -d` might be needed ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885862/6309)) at the time of your `checkout master`.

If you have not yet pushed, you can:

- reset the HEAD and index: `git reset @~`
- delete the extra files (or save them if you need them back in your branch)
- `git add -A`, and commit again.

As the [OP Mohan Prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5874391/mohan-prasad) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651361/commit-on-master-branch-gets-all-the-folders-created-in-the-testing-branch/40651530?noredirect=1#comment68550738_40651530):

> The issue was whenever I was flipping from branch to `master` I did not commit my changes: I just did `git checkout master` which has caused this issue.

---

2022: using the more recent command [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command, a `git switch master` (or `git switch main`, if the [default branch has been renamed to `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67543460/6309)) would avoid the issue.

It would stop because the index or the working tree differs from the new HEAD.

Only `git switch --discard-changes master` would force the branch switch.

Comment: No my question is , I dont want git to commit my branch changes as well. When I am in master and committing my master changes it is adding my branch changes as well..

Comment: @MohanPrasad Hence my answer: when you switched back to master to make your fixes, you should have done a reset --hard and clean to avoid keeping the files created in the other branch.

Comment: For example I have worked 50% on my branch by adding folders and files. Now i flip back to master and make some changes to my other code in master branch. I want to put the code live which i have made on master branch. I commit the changes on master. When I do this it is getting my 50% of branch code to the master commit as well. Thats the problem

Comment: @MohanPrasad All you need to do *before* flipping back to master is to add and commit your files. Then you can flip back to master in confidence, and see only master files.

Comment: @MohanPrasad Again, my edited answer address your current situation, where you have a commit "too big" because it includes files that should not be there.

Comment: The issue was whenever I was flipping from branch to master I did not commit my changes I just did git checkout master which has caused this issue.. that's it nothing else

Comment: @MohanPrasad Exactly. i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.