# Git: files persist while switching between two branch

Tags: git

I have two branches: `master` and `web` and I have my working copy in one directory. In `web` branch I've the folder `foo`. I worked on `foo`'s files and I committed the job. Then I switched to `master` with:

```
git checkout master
```

But `foo` folder is still there in my working copy. It looks strange! `Git status` on master branch tells me the all is fine. But the folder `foo` does not belong to `master` branch. Even If I do

```
git checkout .
```

`web` folder stays in my working copy. To fix I `rm` `web` folder. Now, `git status` keeps telling me the everything is fine and so it is.

But it's very strange, what could have happened and how can I avoid that?

Comment: Have a look at the [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) command . Git is a file tracker and so a folder will still be sitting there when you switch branches. If you do the git clean with the -d option it will remove directories, but I strongly recommend git clean -n to see what will happen before you do other variants!

Comment: What it looks strange to me is that usually my working copy is modified every time I switch to a branch. All folders of the old branch vanish and new folder appears. That's what I want to do but that's not the case of the problem I've described.

Comment: I found a potential explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885850/git-not-removing-files-when-switching-branch/22169659

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a file in `foo` that is commited to master as well. Compare the output of

```
git checkout web
git ls-files foo
```

with

```
git checkout master
git ls-files foo
```

The `ls-files` command should return empty if the folder is not versioned. But I think you will get output anyway.

Git does keep track of which folders are exclusive to a branch and will remove them when switching branches. `git status` also reports on all untracked files that are not in the `.gitignore`.

Comment: `git ls-files foo` is empty in `master`. 'foo' has always been exclusive to `web`. I'm using git carefully, then I do not understand how this happened. Could be atom fault? I'm switching through branch via bash but I'm visualizing the project in atom...

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al foo` from the master branch?

Comment: `No such file or directory` but, as I described, I `rm` the folder manually to keep my working dir aligned to the last `master` commit.

Comment: Could you checkout web and then checkout master again, and try the `ls-files` and `ls -al` commands before the `rm`?

Comment: I've already removed files. I do not understand how it was possible. Maybe a problem with git management of Atom?

Comment: Potential explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885850/git-not-removing-files-when-switching-branch/22169659