# VS Code + Git retains files of other branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch

I'm using VS code + git version 2.20.1 on macOS. Sometimes, when I switch throughout branches, files of other branches are wrongly retained in the current one.

Those files are not present in `.gitignore` and they are not uncommitted changes.

For example if I have those committed files:

- branch_a: file1,file2
- branch_b: file2

if I checkout `branch_a` in VS Code, I commit all changes and then I switch to `branch_b`, I still have `file1` in my working dir.

Oddly enough, `file1` is somehow "invisible" to git. Indeed, this is not considered a potential change to `branch_b`. This is just ignored even if it is actually on the file system. Let me clarify this from the command line point of view.

```
$ [git: branch_a] ls
file1   file2
$ [git: branch_a] git status
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git checkout branch_b
Switched to branch 'branch_b'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/branch_b'.

$ [git: branch_b] ls
file1   file2
```

however, `file1` shouldn't be here, but...

```
$ [git: branch_b] git status
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

working tree is considered clean, and even if I `rm` or I modify the file, git does not detect any changes:

```
$ [git: branch_b] rm file1
$ [git: branch_b] ls
file2

$ [git: branch_b] git status
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This issue is not systematic but it happens only sometimes. A similar problem has been reported [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885850/git-not-removing-files-when-switching-branch) and it seems related to a kind of lock managed by VS Code (or by other Code Editors)

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this behavior and therefore if I can avoid to clean stale files with `git reset --hard` + `git clean -f -d`.

Comment: Are they in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: No, they are not. This is an aberrant behavior, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why git keeps showing my changes when I switch branches (modified,added, deleted files) no matter if I run git add or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531362/why-git-keeps-showing-my-changes-when-i-switch-branches-modified-added-deleted)

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon looks like this is a different problem. I'm gonna edit to specify further

Comment: `git` has a `check-ignore` command to debug what may cause a file to be ignored.

Try running :

    `git check-ignore --verbose file1` and check if this command returns something.

Comment: I've already cleaned up the repo to continue the job :( I can try this command as soon as it happens again

Comment: Also, did you consider if `git update-index` has something for the file?

Comment: No I didn't. As I mentioned, I cannot replicate this issue systematically to look inside it since it happens randomly (or better: after certain events that I still don't get). I hope that there is a known reason for this problem and a known way to avoid it :)

Comment: @LeGEC @eftshift0 I tried your solutions but both return anything about extra files (i.e., "`file1`"). I cannot figure out what it is going on...

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.10 does the same thing. I don't remember VS doing it before the last update (to 16.9).

Comment: Pretty annoying

Comment: I Have an untracked file and nothing to commit working tree clean, and I have only ever worked on one branch in this repo. Very weird.

Answer (score -2):

Before shifting to other branches make sure you have committed all files in one branch then files of other branches will not be reflected in current branch.

Comment: you cannot change branch without commiting.

Comment: As mentioned, you cannot do this using git. You have either to commit or to stash.